# Extract read-only data sections from an archive/lib (ELF i guess?) for compression

Tags: gcc, arm, elf, binutils

**UPDATE:** 
So the question is as follows: My build setup generates an archive/lib (binary output), which I would like to extract some data from, for compression in my case, but that really is not the point.

My instincts tells me, that since a linker can extract constant data from an archive/lib, It should be possible/easy for me to "dump" the binary "contents" of a symbol contained in an archive/lib to e.g. a file....

So that's my question: How to dump binary contents of a symbol in an archive/lib (in ELF format)?

**UPDATE:** 
I am building an application based on [lvgl](https://github.com/littlevgl/lvgl).
To allow texts I'm using the online tool provided by the lvgl maintainer to convert TrueType fonts into C-code (const data) which is linked into the application for rendering texts.
But the resulting data-set for the fonts is getting too large for my available flash memory, but I have a big chunk of un-used RAM. So, I would like to use [heatshrink](https://github.com/atomicobject/heatshrink) to compress the data, and un-compress to RAM at runtime.

This requires, that my build setup can extract the binary data, compress it, and link to flash, so that my run-time code can de-compress it.

I guessed, that I could stuff all the generated font-data into a "lib", extract the binary data, compress it, and link as a "blob" into the application.

But I'm failing to extract the data to compress from the library

E.g. my font-data declaration looks as follows:

```
/*Store the image of the letters (glyph)*/
static const uint8_t _glyph_bitmap[] = 
{ /* const Byte values follow (e.g. 0x00) */ };

static const lv_font_glyph_dsc_t _glyph_dsc[] = 
{ /* struct initialization follows */ }

lv_font_t myfont
{ /* struct initialization follows */ }
```

So I would need to access the myfont, and the declarations it is referencing in binary form.

I have a tool, which creates c-code representing some binary data, to allow the data to be compiled & linked into a final executable (ARM platform, GNU toolchain, custom hardware).
I am running out of flash, but have RAM to spare. So i'm considering compressing some large constant-data sections in a library, and decompress these to RAM as needed.
So I can compile the c-code, and stuff that into an archive. But so far i've had no luck trying to extract the binary data of the constant-data for compression using e.g. objdump or objcopy. But something tells me, that this is possible (and maybe easy even). But how? I've tried to "google" the problem, but came up empty-handed.

Comment: please provide a simple example, maybe a few nops of .text and whatever this data you are talking about a few bytes, something like that a simple link of them into an elf then what you are trying to do to get the data out of the elf and/or what you can get out but what you cant.  how is it you are getting .text out but cant get .data or .rodata or other out?

Comment: unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @old_timer I've tried to clear up what I'm trying to achieve. Suggestions are kindly appreciated.

Comment: if you are already converting the fonts to data in C then you are done, you can instead convert that data to any binary format you want for the application to consume, no need to combine it with other things to then extract it from those things.

Comment: or am I still confused as to the what and why you are trying to extract data from the elf (and why you couldnt just do it anyway with existing or homebrew tools).  Please provide a simple example.  make up some data, a few to handful of bytes, maybe a few lines of assembly language, some nops, compile/assemble/link and then show us in objdump or objcopy or readelf what portions you want to extract from the elf...

Comment: @old_timer: I ended up following your advice, though it didn't technically answer the question I was asking. I've edited the question for more details.

Comment: See: [lgvl new font requirement](https://github.com/littlevgl/lvgl/issues/990) for issues.  The fonts in BMP format has huge amounts of zero values which a bounding box would fix.

Comment: @artlessnoise This is true, but in my case with lots of RAM, this is also easily handled by my compression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Eureka! I figured it out!**

While I fully acknowledge and appreciate the advice given in comments / other answers, it still bothered me that I speculated it should be relatively easy to "play the linker" and extract blobs of hardcoded data from e.g an object-file.

Well, it turns out to be relatively easy (for elf format objects anyways) just as expected by using [readelf](https://linux.die.net/man/1/readelf)

To dump a symbol, I used two steps:

1. Figure out the symbol index, by looking at the symbols in the object:

   `$ readelf --syms company_logo.o`

   `Symbol table '.symtab' contains 17 entries:`

   `Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name`

   `0: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND`

   `1: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS company_logo.c`

   `2: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1`

   `3: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    2`

   `4: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3`

   `5: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4`

   `6: 00000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 $d`

   `7: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6`

   `8: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    7`

   `9: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    9`

   `10: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10`

   `11: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   12`

   `12: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   13`

   `13: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   14`

   `14: 00000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   15`

   `15: 00000000    12 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    4 company_logo`

   `16: 00000000 21879 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    6 company_logo_map`
2. Dump the contents of the symbol.

Now `company_logo_map`was my target, so use its index `6`, as follows:

```
`readelf --hex-dump=6 company_logo.o`

` `

`Hex dump of section '.rodata.company_logo_map':`

`  0x00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................`

`  0x00000010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................`

`  0x00000020 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................`

`  0x00000030 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ................`

`  ... lots more data here`
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extract data from the compiled binary, why not extract it from the generated C code, compress it, and generate equivalent C code with the compressed data?

This approach would probably simplify many aspects of implementation, debugging, and testing.

Comment: I think that using the ttf font (perhaps compressed) on the target flash and port the conversion utility to due the extraction at boot time might also be fruitful.  A vector font will support italic, bold, different weights and sizes in one font whereas bitmaps will require glyphs for all.  Pruning un-needed glyphs might also be worthwhile.

Comment: @Jeremy: This is essentially what old_timer suggested in his comments, and was the solution I eventually used. This solves my problem, but does NOT answer my question, which (out of interest) still stands: How to extract symbol-contents of objects/archives.